# My PC has just started Freezing

Tags: libreoffice

I am recently new to Ubuntu - Sept 19 - and very very happy so far.
Until three days ago that is, whilst working on my tax return, so fairly important stuff - when my PC just froze.
The screen appears the same, my mouse pointer still moves around the screen but does not operate any of the buttons and the keyboard is totally non responsive.
I have not made any recent changes or installed anything ( hardware / software ) new.
It happens EVERY time I try to print a Libre Office Calc document.
If I use my printer to print from a pdf - it works just fine.
It sometimes happens when I try to open more than one file window and one or two other random things...
I have tried to remove and then re-instal LO Calc, but it hasn't fixed my problem.
I am currently downloading an ISO image so that I can make a bootable USB and then try running from that to see if that makes any difference.

Would any of you have any ideas as to what might be happening or how I might fix it.
Thank you,
Ian.R

Edit 1: Thank you K7AAY,
Yup, running from my new LiveUSB, LO-Calc seems to work fine when I ask it to print ( although the output is garbage as I have not installed the printer driver ) but, it does try to print without causing a problem.
My system : AMD® Fx(tm)-8350 eight-core processor × 8, 6.7 GiB RAM, Graphics ; NV98, GNOME ; 3.28.2, and running 64bit Ubuntu BB 18.04.3LTS

Comment: Testing with a LiveUSB is a _very_ good idea. Once you've done that, please click [edit] and update the question to let us know your findings. OBTW: What's the make and model of your PC, and which version number of Ubuntu is in use?

Comment: Man that was QUICK ! I love this place already...

Comment: Thank you, just off to try my new live stick Ian.R